# How to compress a .zip to a .gz in java?

Tags: java, server, zip, gzipoutputstream

I want to compress a normal file to a .zip and then compress it as gzip file without creating a new file.

For example let's say that I have a pdf document **doc.pdf**, what I have to get is: `doc.pdf.zip.gz`

I don't want to creat a new file called `doc.pdf.zip` and then open it and gzip it.

I'm working with a server to get the file from the browser and return it back, this is my function:

```
 public void ZIPandGZIP(String fileName, OutputStream os, String header) throws FileNotFoundException
 {
    File file = new File(fileName);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] data = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
    try {
        dos.writeBytes(header);
        ZipOutputStream zpos = new ZipOutputStream(os); 
        zpos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileName));
        GZIPOutputStream gos = (new GZIPOutputStream(zpos));
        fis.read(data);
        gos.write(data);

        zpos.flush();
        zpos.close();
        gos.flush();
        gos.close();
        dos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

I get a file `doc.pdf.zip.gz` but it has a corrupted file `doc.pdf` and not zipped why??

Comment: move the `close()` calls to a `finally` block

Comment: Thanks, i did that but it keeps returning the same.

Comment: had nothing to do with your problem, just best practice :P

Comment: Just wondering, why? Why compress it twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can create a temporary file for the zip add it to gzip and then delete the zip that was created. The below code sample should help you with that.

```
public void ZIPandGZIP(String fileName, OutputStream os, String header) throws FileNotFoundException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    ZipOutputStream zos = null;
    File tempZipFile = File.createTempFile(fileName, ".zip")
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(tempZipFile);
        zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
        ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(fileName);
        zos.putNextEntry(ze);
        fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);

        int len;
        while ((len = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        zos.closeEntry();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (fis != null) {
            fis.close();
        }
        if (zos != null) {
            zos.close();
        }
        if (fos != null) {
            fos.close();
        }
    }

    addGzipFileToStream(tempZipFile, os, header);
}

private void addGzipFileToStream(File zipFile, OutputStream os, String header) throws FileNotFoundException {

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    GZIPOutputStream gzos = null;
    FileInputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
        dos.writeBytes(header);

        gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(os);
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(zipFile);

        int len;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            gzos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        gzos.finish();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
        if (gzos != null) {
            gzos.close();
        }
        if (dos != null) {
            dos.close();
        }
        zipFile.delete();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, actually the purpose of my function is to gzip a zipped file so inside the .gz file i should have a .zip file tha has my document..

Comment: oh okay. You could use temporary file for this purpose. I am not sure if you can do that in memory.

Comment: @PaulErdemBursh I have updated my answer based on using a temporary file for the zip. Check it out. Hope it helps.